# In a function's signature, what does the asterisk mean in Python when it's not followed by an identifier name?

Tags: python

I know the meaning and usage of `*args`. But sometimes there is nothing like `args` after the `*`. For example, in the function [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html)

```
def pprint(object, stream=None, indent=1, width=80, depth=None, *,
           compact=False):
    """Pretty-print a Python object to a stream [default is sys.stdout]."""
    printer = PrettyPrinter(
        stream=stream, indent=indent, width=width, depth=depth,
        compact=compact)
    printer.pprint(object)
```

there is an `*` in the signature. What does it mean?

Answer (score 8):

Arguments *after* the `*` are [keyword-only](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/). The `*` *"soaks up"* any additional positional arguments, so if you defined:

```
def foo(x, y, *, z):
    print(x, y, z)
```

then calling:

```
foo(1, 2, 3)
```

wouldn't work, as no `z` is supplied and only two positional arguments are expected:

```
>>> foo(1, 2, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    foo(1, 2, 3)
TypeError: foo() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

`z` **must** now be supplied by keyword:

```
>>> foo(1, 2, z=3)
1 2 3
```

You *can* do this with a standard `*args`, but using `*` makes it clear that you don't want any additional positional arguments and causes an error to be raised if any end up in the `*`. As the PEP puts it:

> The second syntactical change is to allow the argument name to
>   be omitted for a varargs argument. The meaning of this is to
>   allow for keyword-only arguments for functions that would not
>   otherwise take a varargs argument

Comment: What do you mean exactly by `*` soaking up additional positional arguments? I'm confused because we can't pass additional positional arguments (like in `foo(1, 2, 3, z=4)`).